# What is the best practice to send multiple select query on search form?

Tags: php, forms

I'm using [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) `Multiple Select` on my search form.

Example :

[image]

What is the best practice to send & get `query string` with multiple select on my search form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd imagine having the html as `<input type="hidden" name="chosen[]" value="<!-- id or whatever you want to work with-->" />`

If you can have it through that Chosen thingie, that is.

Then you can simply get an array on serverside:

```
$arr = $_POST['chosen'];

print_r($arr);
```

---

```
array(0 => 2,
      1 => 10,
      2 => 37)
```

Given result if you selected the ids 2, 10 and 37.

Comment: Great.. how about if I want use a `$_GET` and what is query on URL should be done? `/search/q=??` The main reason I want use get is the results have a pagination, back & next.

Comment: So the search query will be looks like `/search/?chosen[]=1&chosen[]=2&chosen[]=3` right?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably look at serialize: http://php.net/serialize
And then name your inputs like name="selects[]" to pick it up, as an array